# Creating node and set ID for it without duplicating field

Tags: neo4j

I created a node with given id,

```
create (n:Entry) set n.id=1111
```

but database created two field id in node, one default and one by myself.
[image]

Could you help me how to set id for node when creating without generating two similar field "id"?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi! The `<id>` property is the internal Neo4j id that is autogenerated. Since is just internal you can basically ignore it and just rely on the `id` property you generate. Also, to be able to access that internal id you should use the `id` function like this `MATCH (n) RETURN id(n)` https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-id

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two values you see are

- the internal node identifier `id(n)` of Neo4j, here `12` and
- an attribute `n.id`, here `1111`.

You can access them both from Cypher unsing the syntax shown above,
`MATCH (n:Entry) RETURN id(n), n.id` yields:

| `id(n)` | `n.id` |
| --- | --- |
| `12` | `1111` |

You cannot change the internal ID from Cypher, it is assigned when the node is created by the system. The only way I know to control which node gets which internal ID (you should never have to do this, rethink your software design!) is using the [Neo4j Admin Import](https://neo4j.com/docs/operations-manual/current/tools/neo4j-admin-import/) tool with the `--id-type=ACTUAL` option. This only works for nodes that are batch-imported into a previously empty database however.